# PHP Directory_Seperator?

Tags: php, path

I'm following PHP with MySQL beyond the basics of Kevin Skoglund course.
He uses a Mac while I use Windows.For moment I'm at Initializing files and path constants and sth is not working properly when I run this 
Kevin's Code

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 

define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'Users'.DS.'kevin'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

I'm trying for windows like this

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

but not working, how can I?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspeled DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just write:-

```
DEFINE('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and then write your path as:

```
$path = 'www'.DS.'app'.DS.'index';
```

PHP accepts both \ and / as valid path separators in all OS. So You can use / in your code without any problem.